# Transaction log gets full

Tags: sql, sql-server, transaction-log

We are on SQL Server 2016. Our recovery mode is FULL. Auto-growth is set to 4GB.
Drive size is 1TB. Transaction log backup frequency is 2 hours.

We have an issue with the transaction log getting full very frequently. Our data size is approximately 1.2TB.

Can someone please suggest what we could do to get rid of this issue. Any additional setting that we could change or check for?
PS: I'm a beginner in this field, so would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you do more frequent backs up of your transaction log than every 2 hours. 2 hours, for a log back up (in my opinion) is a long time. I would expect every 30 minutes at most in truth, but every 10/15 minutes is far more common. Every 2 hours means you're happy to loose up to 2 hours of data in the event of a failure. That *can* be a lot of data.

Comment: You should find someone more experienced to help with this problem.  You are dealing with data integrity and recoverability issues, so the impact of whatever  you do might be subtle or might cause big problems down the road.

Answer (score 1):

The log must be sized to accommodate all activity between log backups at a minimum. The log backup frequency should be driven by your recovery point objective (RPO), which is the maximum acceptable data loss as defined by the business.

However, you may need to schedule log backups more frequently to keep the transaction log size reasonable. 2 hours is apparently not often enough in your environment so you need to either increase the log size or increase the log backup frequency.